# AWS signature 4: Java and Crypto-JS does not march

Tags: java, php, amazon-web-services, cryptojs

I am using java to do some post with AWS signature header. The signing process is below

```
    private String calculateSignature(String stringToSign) {
        try {
                byte[] signatureKey = getSignatureKey(secretAccessKey, currentDate, regionName, serviceName);
                byte[] signature = HmacSHA256(stringToSign, signatureKey);
                String strHexSignature = bytesToHex(signature);
                return strHexSignature;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
    }

    private byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key) throws Exception {
        String algorithm = "HmacSHA256";
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm));
        return mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
    }

    private byte[] getSignatureKey(String key, String date, String regionName, String serviceName) throws Exception {
        byte[] kSecret = ("AWS4" + key).getBytes("UTF8");
        byte[] kDate = HmacSHA256(date, kSecret);
        byte[] kRegion = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
        byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
        byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256(aws4Request, kService);
        return kSigning;
    }

    private String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        final StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
        for(byte b : bytes)
            hexString.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        return hexString.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
    }
```

However, when I send use this signature, it does not match the signature calculated by the server. The server is written in PHP, and it us Crypto-JS to calculate the signature. I have compared two strings need to sign and Canonical Request between Java and PHP. They are matching.

I have checked space, command and other characteries. but cannot figure out why. Are Java HmacSHA256 and crypto-js HmacSHA256 different? Or something wrong with bytesToHex method?

The Java output of Canonical Request

```
POST
/

content-length:667
content-type:application/json
host:host.name.com
x-amz-date:20171205T012629Z
x-amz-target:_20141201.XXXXXXX

content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target
c5b31b699700e6debe4548836a723f89b73ffcef6570e1bed4c534c0f247dc26
```

The PHP returns:

```
POST
/

content-length:667
content-type:application/json
host:host.name.com
x-amz-date:20171205T012629Z
x-amz-target:_20141201.XXXXXXX

content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target
c5b31b699700e6debe4548836a723f89b73ffcef6570e1bed4c534c0f247dc26
```

Any help or any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet would be to hex-encode the intermediate keys (secret, date, region, service, signing) keys on both platforms and compare the intermediate values.  Any mismatch means the problem is earlier in your flow.  You don't show what you're passing, but the date value is 8 bytes `yyyymmdd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The reason was the algorithm of the secret key was changed, but i was not aware of that change